# How to set a custom theme for an activity in eclipse for android

Tags: android, eclipse, themes

How can I define a custom theme for my activity? I was trying to do it by android manifest, But I had no Idea about how am I going to do that!
PLease write down the code

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to create a custom theme style in android:
1. To an individual View, by adding the style attribute to a View element in the XML for your layout.
2. Or, to an entire Activity or application, by adding the android:theme attribute to the `<activity>` or `<application>` element in the Android manifest.

Please refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

To set a theme for all the activities of your application, open the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and edit the  tag to include the android:theme attribute with the style name. For example:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```